# Why does the 2-tuple Functor instance only apply the function to the second element?

Tags: haskell, tuples, functor

```
import Control.Applicative

main = print $ fmap (*2) (1,2)
```

produces `(1,4)`. I would expect it it to produce `(2,4)` but instead the function is applied only to the second element of the tuple.

**Update** I've basically figured this out almost straight away. I'll post my own answer in a minute..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Functor` instance is actually from the [GHC.Base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-625) module which is imported by `Control.Applicative`.

Trying to write the instance I want, I can see that it won't work, given the definition of tuples; the instance requires just one type parameter, while the 2-tuple has two.

A valid `Functor` instance would at least have to be on tuples, `(a,a)` that have the same type for each element, but you cannot do anything sneaky, like define the instance on:

```
 type T2 a = (a,a)
```

because instance types aren't permitted to be synonyms.

The above restricted 2-tuple synonym is logically the same as the type:

```
data T2 a = T2 a a
```

which *can* have a Functor instance:

```
instance Functor T2 where
    fmap f (T2 x y) = T2 (f x) (f y)
```

As Gabriel remarked in the comments, this can be useful for branching structures or concurrency.

Comment: Actually, that IS useful as an instance of the functor class.  For example, I can define a tree as `type Tree a = Free T2 a`.  In fact, most uses of that type (in its capacity as a functor) involve branching or concurrency of some sort.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you want to specify which part of the tuple to map over, you can use `Control.Lens`. A `Setter` is like a `Functor` instance that you specify explicitly, so `over _1 (+1) (5,3)` ==> `(6,3)`; `over _2 (*2) ("funny,2)` ==> `("funny",4)`; `over both length ("hi","there")` ==> `(2,5)`; `over (both._1) (*10) ((1,2),(3,4))` ==> `((10,2),(30,4))`.

Comment: You can also use arrows if you want to run it on the first element or second element: `first` and `second`.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I would much prefer the simpler `Bifunctor` versions of those functions in this case; it's easier to understand and generalizes in what I think is probably a more common direction.

Answer (score 33):

Let me answer this with a question: Which output do you expect for:

```
main = print $ fmap (*2) ("funny",2)
```

You *can* have something as you want (using `data Pair a = Pair a a` or so), but as `(,)` may have different types in their first and second argument, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 26):

Pairs are, essentially, defined like this:

```
data (,) a b = (,) a b
```

The `Functor` class looks like this:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Since the types of function arguments and results must have kind `*` (i.e. they represent values rather than type functions that can be applied further or more exotic things), we must have `a :: *`, `b :: *`, and, most importantly for our purposes, `f :: * -> *`. Since `(,)` has kind `* -> * -> *`, it must be applied to a type of kind `*` to obtain a type suitable to be a `Functor`. Thus

```
instance Functor ((,) x) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (x,a) -> (x,b)
```

So there's actually no way to write a `Functor` instance doing anything else.

---

One useful class that offers more ways to work with pairs is `Bifunctor`, from `Data.Bifunctor`.

```
class Bifunctor f where
  bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f a c -> f b d
  bimap f g = first f . second g

  first :: (a -> b) -> f a y -> f b y
  first f = bimap f id

  second :: (c -> d) -> f x c -> f x d
  second g = bimap id g
```

This lets you write things like the following (from `Data.Bifunctor.Join`):

```
  newtype Join p a =
    Join { runJoin :: p a a }

  instance Bifunctor p => Functor (Join p) where
    fmap f = Join . bimap f f . runJoin
```

`Join (,)` is then essentially the same as `Pair`, where

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
```

Of course, you can also just use the `Bifunctor` instance to work with pairs directly.

Comment: Why is ``-- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (y,x,a) -> (y,x,b)`` not working for 3-tuples?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev It would, if you defined a `Functor` instance for `((,,) x y)`. `(x,y)` and `(x,y,z)` are *very* different (families of) types, as there is no single "tuple" type (family).

Comment: *"So there's actually no way to write a Functor instance doing anything else."* What about `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (a,x) -> (b,x)`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, that's just not the type `fmap` has to have according to the definition of the `Functor` class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Theoretically, could one define `instance Functor ((*, x))`? (Not sure what the correct notation is for an unapplied type, so I used `*`.)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, it's a bit hard to guess what you might mean, but one type that's occasionally useful is `newtype Flip f a b = Flip { unFlip :: f b a }`.