# Where is the Functor implementation of `((,) e)`, the type annotation container?

Tags: haskell, tuples, typeclass, functor

The [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia) lists `((,) e)` as an instance of `Functor` and describes it as follows.

> `((,) e)` represents a container which holds an “annotation” of type e along with the actual value it holds. It might be clearer to write it as `(e,)`, by analogy with an operator section like `(1+)`, but that syntax is not allowed in types (although it is allowed in expressions with the `TupleSections` extension enabled). However, you can certainly think of it as `(e,)`.

I am looking at the implementations of various typeclasses to improve my understanding. Currently looking at Functor implementations but cannot seem to find some of them, such as `((,) e)` and `((->) e)`. Where is the functor instance for `((,) e)` implemented?

Comment: Tangential note: "type annotation container" suggests something that happens at type level; simply "annotation container" works better as a description. (It might also be worth emphasising that it is just a pair, and "annotation container" is just a different way of thinking about it, that is, as a value with something else attached.)

Comment: In ghci, `:info (,)` will tell you the source of instances for the pair type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the 2-tuple Functor instance only apply the function to the second element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442544/why-does-the-2-tuple-functor-instance-only-apply-the-function-to-the-second-elem)

Answer (score 3):

[Here it is](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-648):

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
    fmap f (x,y) = (x, f y)
```

In general, a convenient way to find instances is looking at the instances list in either [the documentation entry for the class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor) or the one for the data type (in almost all cases you'll find the instance in at least one of them) and following the source link.

As Li-yao Xia notes in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092032/where-is-the-functor-implementation-of-e-the-type-annotation-container#comment75205907_44092032), another route is using `:i (,)` in GHCi, which will list all instances in scope for `(,)` along with the module they are defined. (In this specific case, that happens to be `GHC.Base`, which is not directly accessible through [the entry page for the *base* docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0), though it can be found in [the source tree listing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/src/) as well as through source links scattered across the docs, such as the one in the list of instances in `Data.Functor`.)

Answer (score 0):

It’s declared in [Control.Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#control.i:ic:Functor:Functor:37) (among other places).  The documentation includes [a link to the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-648) for GHC.  Other implementations may vary.

Answer (score 0):

`((,) e)` also has a very "containerish" comonad instance in [`Control.Comonad`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad.html):

- `extract :: (e, a) -> a` discards the context and returns the value. I sometimes use this instead of `snd`.
- `duplicate :: (e, a) -> (e, (e, a))` puts both the value and context in the value.
- `extend :: ((e, a) -> b) -> (e, a) -> (e, b)` transforms the value taking the context into account.