# Iterate over matrices of varying shape

Tags: generics, rust, nalgebra

I'm implementing [MATLAB's `ode45`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) in Rust, but attempting to make a major improvement.  If a user of MATLAB's `ode45` wants to integrate a matrix and a vector simultaneously, they have to flatten the matrix and append or prepend the vector before passing it to MATLAB's `ode45` only to undo that process when attempting to make use of the solution. I would like for a user of *my* `ode45` to be able to pass a collection<sup>1</sup> containing arbitrarily-shaped nalgebra `Matrix` types.

I've seen that [I can't iterate over tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640774/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-a-tuple) unless I [use a fancy macro and implement a trait for every size of tuple the macro is to be used on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148544/how-to-iterate-or-map-over-tuples). I also can't use a `Matrix` array, because the types aren't strictly the same if the shapes are arbitrary.

An important detail about integrators is that you must provide a function that models the first-order differential equation. From the user's perspective, this would be fairly easy, since they could simply write a function that takes their specific tuple and returns the same. The trouble is figuring out how to handle whatever the user may want to integrate simultaneously.

Below is a snippet that illustrates what I want to be able to do:

```rust
let system_dynamics(y: &(&SVector<f64, 4>, &SMatrix<f64, 4, 4>)
    -> (SVector<f64, 4>, SMatrix<f64, 4, 4>) {
  return (SVector::<f64, 4>::new(y.0[2], y.0[3], 0.0, -9.81),
          SMatrix::<f64, 4, 4>::new(y.0[2],    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                       0.0, y.0[2],    0.0,    0.0,
                                       0.0,    0.0, y.0[2],    0.0,
                                       0.0,    0.0,    0.0, y.0[2])
  );
}

let y0 = (SVector::<f64, 4>::new(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0),
          SMatrix::<f64, 4, 4>::zeros());
let t0 = 0.0;
let tf = 10.0;
let (t, y) = ode45(|_t, y| system_dynamics(&y), [t0, tf], y0);

println!("{}: ({}, {})", t.last().unwrap, y.last().unwrap().0, y.last().unwrap().1);
// Should print something along the lines of
// 10: (
//   ┌        ┐
//   │    100 │
//   │ -390.5 │
//   │     10 │
//   │  -88.1 │
//   └        ┘
// ,
//   ┌                    ┐
//   │ 100  0.0  0.0  0.0 │
//   │ 0.0  100  0.0  0.0 │
//   │ 0.0  0.0  100  0.0 │
//   │ 0.0  0.0  0.0  100 │
//   └                    ┘
// )
```

I already have a working and tested implementation of `ode45` that works on an arbitrarily-shaped `Matrix`; all I need help with is figuring out how to accept multiple `Matrix` types of arbitrary dimension that need to be integrated simultaneously.

---

<sup>1: by "collection", I mean something of arbitrary length that can be iterated over.</sup>